# Обработка syscall,которые поступают в ядро Linux

Tags: linux, c

Суть задачи такова, что нужно блочить определенные процессы. Было предпринято решение создать хук, который перехватывал бы системные вызовы, поступающие к ядру.

Но потом встал вопрос: нет ли такого функционала на уровне ядра?

Comment: Если блокировать нужно на вашей системе, то почему бы просто не настроить её правильно? Если блокировать нужно на пользовательской системе, это вообще-то агрессивно-враждебное поведение по отношению к пользователю, очень нетипичное для линукса.

Comment: @VladD суть в том, что бы написать что-то схожее на firewall, который блочит нужные приложения...

Comment: А какой юзкейс? Для чего такое может пригодиться? (У меня чисто теоретический интерес, я не специалист по линуксу и его ядру.)

Comment: Вы про модули ядра?

Comment: @avp да, о них речь.

Comment: В чем именно затруднения?

Comment: @avp затруднение в реализации. Был вариант написания модуля для хука для чтения таблицы системных вызовов и соответственно отсылки нужного сигнала. Но,повторюсь, есть ли реализация подобного хука на уровне ядра? Слышали ли вы что-то про LSM фрейм?

Comment: Имеете в виду [LSM framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Security_Modules), ограничивающий реализацию модулей?  [Подобные штучки](https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-hook-system-calls-in-Linux) Вы ведь видели? И самое непонятное, а как **не на уровне ядра** Вы собираетесь перехватывать syscall? Подменой libc.so (или module это не ядро)?

Comment: @avp выходит, вариант лишь один : хук на таблицу системных вызовов...

Comment: @avp а как же inode_permission hook в LSM?

Answer (score 2):

если вам надо остановить какой-нибудь процесс, пошлите ему сигнал *SIGSTOP*. цитата из `man 7 signal`:

> The signals SIGKILL and SIGSTOP cannot be caught, blocked, or ignored.

чтобы процесс продолжил выполнение после остановки, пошлите ему сигнал *SIGCONT*.

подробности — в `man 7 signal` или, например, в [интернете](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html).

Comment: @alexander_barakin Будьте добры, обьясните, как отослать нужному процессу SIGSTOP

Comment: @Max, в man-е же, в разделе *Sending a signal*, приведены шесть функций, с помощью которых можно посылать сигналы тем или иным сущностям (процессам, нитям, группам процессов). по каждой из функций есть своя man-страница. или, если вы смотрите на веб-страницу, ссылку на которую я привёл, то просто перейдите по ссылке под названием функции.